# How to check if *any* GET field is populated html php

Tags: php, html, url, dom, xss

Situation: An attempt to prevent **DOM-based XSS**.

My solution: Check if ANY GET fields are populated, since most DOM-based XSS appends to the end of URLs such as `https://example.com/page?<script>XSS</script>`

Question: Is there any way I can check if there is anything filled after **"?"**, which usually holds the `$_GET` fields.

Additional information: I tried `$_GET['']."%"` to try to fish out anything that is there, did not work.

Comment: You can check the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, Note if you just do `var_dump($_GET);` you will see nothing in the brwoser because  of the tags. You have to look at the sourecode in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what appears to me using `http://domain.tld/page?<script>XSS</script>`.

`$_GET` is not empty as you say.

[image]

Just iterate every single `$_GET` attribute and make sure they are sanitized prior any data processing with your business model.

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $attribute)
{
    // do something with $key or $attribute!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several way  possible  .. eg:

You could iterate  over $_GET

```
 foreach( $_GET as $key => $value) {

  // if any you can perform your check 

 }
```

or you can check for

```
  if (isset($_GET) {

   count($_GET) ;   // the you know the number of elemns
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_GET. Just `print_r($_GET);` If you have anything in query string after ? then data will be in $_GET array. If the $_GET array is blank then there is no data in query string

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Go to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php